# How to assign a value to an Array in a for- loop

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

First time the loop is being executed:
A value is assigned to `PlaatSnoepArray[0,0] and PlaatSnoepArray[0,1]`.

Second time the loop is being executed:
A value is assigned to `PlaatSnoepArray[1,0] and PlaatSnoepArray[1,1]` 
AND the values of `PlaatSnoepArray[0,0]` and `PlaatSnoepArray[0,1]` are set to 0.

Third time the loop is being executed:
A value is assigned to `PlaatSnoepArray[2,0]` and `PlaatSnoepArray[2,1]`.
AND the values of `PlaatSnoepArray[1,0]` and `PlaatSnoepArray[1,1]` are set to `0`.

How can i prevent that the values are set back to 0 ?

```
    static Random Rangen = new Random();
    static void PlaatsSnoep(int aantal)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
        {

            int SnoepX = Rangen.Next(25, 94);
            int SnoepY = Rangen.Next(3, 23);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(SnoepX, SnoepY);
            Console.WriteLine("0");

            int[,] PlaatssnoepArray = new int[aantal,2];

            PlaatssnoepArray[i, 0] = SnoepX;
            PlaatssnoepArray[i, 1] = SnoepY;

        }
```

Comment: 15 seconds, 4 answers damn

Comment: @Habib Surely a record of some kind?

Comment: I was about to comment, but I even got beat to commenting. Now it's the race for edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing your array inside the loop, move it out

```
static Random Rangen = new Random();
static void PlaatsSnoep(int aantal)
{

    int[,] PlaatssnoepArray = new int[aantal,2];
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {

        int SnoepX = Rangen.Next(25, 94);
        int SnoepY = Rangen.Next(3, 23);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(SnoepX, SnoepY);
        Console.WriteLine("0");


        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 0] = SnoepX;
        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 1] = SnoepY;

    }
}
```

And what about using a `List<Point>()` instead of an array?

```
    List<Point> PlaatssnoepList = new List<Point>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {
        Point p = new Point(Rangen.Next(25, 94), Rangen.Next(3, 23));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(p.X, p.Y);
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        PlaatssnoepList.Add(p)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `array` outside the `for` loop:

```
    int[,] PlaatssnoepArray = new int[aantal,2];

    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {

        int SnoepX = Rangen.Next(25, 94);
        int SnoepY = Rangen.Next(3, 23);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(SnoepX, SnoepY);
        Console.WriteLine("0");

        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 0] = SnoepX;
        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 1] = SnoepY;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i prevent that the values are set back to 0 ?

You need to move the creation of the `PlaatssnoepArray` outside the loop. Currently, each iteration assigns to its own instane of `int[aantal,2]`, which goes out of scope and gets thrown away as soon as the loop iteration is over.

```
int[,] PlaatssnoepArray = new int[aantal,2];
for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
{
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array declaration is inside the loop, move it outside.

```
int[,] PlaatssnoepArray = new int[aantal,2];
for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
    {
        int SnoepX = Rangen.Next(25, 94);
        int SnoepY = Rangen.Next(3, 23);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(SnoepX, SnoepY);
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 0] = SnoepX;
        PlaatssnoepArray[i, 1] = SnoepY;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your array out of the loop..